# performance map c++ find (g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3))

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a performance sensitive application which has code like

```
for each record r
    processRecord(r)
```

then

```
processRecord( record r )
{
    for each field in record r 
      processField (f)
}
```

When our application starts it uses an xml file to populate a map . Lets call it M . The map is of  string and a structure . where the strung is the name in  the xml tag and structure consists of all other elements in the xml  .

The processing of each filed in processField is a long operation where we need the help of the above map M to find its properties as specified in map and processing the field accordingly .

We have huge sets of data which comes from outside and when I do my profiling , I find that maximum time is spent in doing a find operation on map M .

The map is composed from fields in xml and I can safely say that the map will between  size 50-200.

The number of records sent to our application is 300 per second & each record has feilds same as map size .

A quick search on net suggests that one can try to use unordered_map but its not available in my old c++ compiler as we haven't moved to C++11 and thats something I cannot control . Also on net it seemed that for smaller sets like mine map and unordered_map will give similar results .

We are not concerned if map creation takes time as its a one time activity but want fast find()s .
So when I did my profiling , I find that maximum time is spent in doing a find operation on map M and i wish to reduce it . Any suggestion ?

The specific api of map being refered to me by my profiler are  (top 2)

```
1)  std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >::operator() (this=0x7f1a679eb1bf, __x=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_function.h:489

and 

2) #0  0x00000000005e3d7f in std::_Rb_tree<int, int, std::_Identity<int>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::~_Rb_tree (this=0x7f1a679ebf72, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:613
#1  0x00000000005e3d42 in std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::~set (this=0x7f1a679eb5d0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_set.h:88
```

**EDIT**
I  was able to improve perf using the recommendations below  :) . I tested for small set of random data . My cpu usage with std:map was ~12.24% in std::_Rb_tree* .. With boost::unordered_map i get only 4.34% in boost::unordered_detail::* So it means i have ~7% cpu for other activities .

Comment: What kind of data it the map holding, just ints?

Comment: Current GCC is 4.9 in december 2014. You should upgrade your compiler

Comment: If, as you've said, you can't upgrade, then perhaps the boost unordered map might be useful.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/unordered/comparison.html

Comment: @MorphingDragon The map is of  string and a structure .  updating question as well

Comment: @RetiredNinja i dont think using unordered map  will help as the size of the structure is small . Also isn't unordered map a feature of higher version of c++ compiler which is not availiable to me .

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch which version of gcc i should i use , is not in my control .  Its something driven at organisation level . I dont want to go that route and wish to know if there is something I can do with my current gcc version .

Comment: @MAG The only way for you to know is to try it and see.  Boost works with older compilers.  I'm not sure what other advice you're looking for.  If most of what you do is find then it makes sense that find is your #1 item on the profile.

Comment: @RetiredNinja .. oops sorry . I didnt read boost . My bad . let me try and i will update this thread if it helps .

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks and i was able to improve perf a bit :)  . I tested for small set of random data . My cpu usage with std:map was ~12.24%  in std::_Rb_tree* .. With boost::unordered i get only 4.34% in boost::unordered_detail::*

Comment: @MAG Is the data you're reading from the XML files static? I assume you're allowed plenty of preprocessing?

Comment: @MorphingDragon  . Yes its static . Users enter their configuration in the XML and that remains constant through out the run . If  a person needs other configuration he needs to stop the application , change the xml and restart the application .

Comment: @MAG A Trie will have have better worst case performance than a Hash Map. But since your search size is so small it might not be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own questions as this problem might be occurring to other users as well.
I was able to improve perf using the recommendations in the comments section of my question .

**@RetiredNinja** suggested me to use  boost unordered map

To understand the same i referred to [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/682927/stl-map-and-unordered-map-difference) . Relevant text from that site is this
**An ordered map** is usually implemented on the basis of an ordered tree, for example red-black-tree in STL's case. Tree manipulations are relatively expensive, but the tree uses very little storage.
**An unordered map** is usually implemented as a hash table; the newer STL implementation offer such a map as well. Hash table are very fast, but have some storage overhead and can only grew to a certain number of nodes before they become inefficient.

Since I am more bothered about find calls and insertions will happen just 1 time I thought of trying an unordered map  **boost::unordered_map** . Space restriction was not as important to me as my map size was small (200 elements at most) .

I tested for small set of random data . I ran my perf tests to figure out which api was now consuming cpu cycles more . My cpu usage with using std:map added up to  ~12.24% in std::_Rb_tree*  calls .. With boost::unordered_map I get only 4.34% in boost::unordered_detail::* calls when I added them all . So it means I saved around 7% cpu for other activities .

I will still wait if other people can give me some more approaches but for now this helped a lot .